# Implementing Facebook into a Tab Bar Application Xcode Project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I am reading how to implement facebook into my iOS SDK from the facebook developer website: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#ios, but the setup is based on a view-based application. First of all I tried their example using a View-Based application as well and after implementing their code, I debug and ran the project in iOS Simulator and it's giving me an error saying:

On debug under

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
```

[image]

So I have no clue what's going on here, so I hope someone can help me with this error: 1 thing I might point out, I don't know if creating the instance variable 'Facebook' in the header `Facebook *facebook` should be the name of one of my UIVewController subclass, so I dont really know. In addition, should my facebook application run in a UIWebView in Interface Builder?

Also my project is based on a tab bar application. So on my 3rd Tab Bar item, I have like 3 buttons all opening a new view that each have a WebView, and one of my buttons are the facebook application that will open.

Please let me know if it's not clear, thanks again!

Comment: Need help fast? For the amount you're paying us, I think the normal speed of service is a good deal. Please don't ask for fast responses, it's considered impolite here, even if you *do* have a deadline.

Comment: "does not implement protocol" means that your class (the 'self') should be implementing certain delegate methods in the .m file (see FBSessionDelegate), and declaring that it has implemented them, in the .h file. See this question for a better example of implementing a protocol: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788882/iphone-sdk-warning-class-myappviewcontroller-does-not-implement-the-uitabbardel (obviously the details will be different for your facebook thing, but you get the idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in header file

specify that `<FBSessionDelegate>`

before this you have to import the `facebook.h`

and then implement the required method for `fbsessiondelegate` protocol